# How to add gradient stroke effect on a layout in android xml?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am seeking assistance in implementing a gradient stroke effect within my Android project. Despite my attempts to utilize techniques such as layering, shape vectors, and others, I have not been able to achieve the desired outcome. I have provided a screenshot showcasing the specific effect I am aiming to replicate. In the attached image, you will observe two CardViews, each exhibiting a distinctive stroke effect on their left sides, with a combination of white and green colors. I am eager to learn the recommended approach to accomplish this effect. Your guidance and expertise would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make an image with the gradient and background color you want, with the curved corners you want, and set it as the background for the entire view.  It will stretch to fill the view and should give you something at least close you can iterate on.